# CoreData: No existing entry for row 0 but for row 1,2,3

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I made an CoreData app which also includes an UITableView. The app loads all CoreData entries into the UITableViewCells at startup. I saved 5 entries into CoreData (of type String). If each UITableViewCell is going to be filled with the correct entries at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` there's no entry (nil) at `indexPath.row: 0` but at row 1,2,3,4 and 5 there's an existing entry. I don't know why but each time if the cell with the `indexPath.row = 0` loads the app crashes with the reason: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. The `optional value` is an attribute of an entity of my core data model. Does someone knows why this error occurs each time if `indexPath.row = 0`? If you need more informations feel free to ask me. Thanks a lot for your help.

Get value:

```
let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as NSManagedObject
var dateFromCell = object.valueForKey("datum") as NSDate?
var dateString = Date.toString(date: dateFromCell!)
```

Save value:

```
let myDate:NSDate = NSDate()
let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
let entity = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entity!
let newManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entity.name!, inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
newManagedObject.setValue(myDate, forKey: "datum")

// Save the context.
    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !context.save(&error) {
        abort()
    }
```

Comment: At index `0` in your array you are storing an optional. If an optional contains a nil value and you unwrap it your program will crash. Hence the error message `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. Check the contents of the optional using the `if let` syntax before using the optional value.

Answer (score 1):

Go back and look at your array first before trying to diagnose the cell. Apparently there is no value at index 0 in your array. Place a breakpoint and view your arrays values. Using optionals will prevent a crash if used properly. (ie. ?? "" or anything similar). It's hard to diagnose without seeing your actual code so please feel free to share the problem areas.

Comment: I updated the question with some code. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is in that part of the code, it is here:

```
var dateFromCell = object.valueForKey("datum") as NSDate?
var dateString = Date.toString(date: dateFromCell!)
//                                               ^-- Here
```

`dateFromCell` is nil. Which leads to a crash when you force unwrap it.

This might have happened because you accidentally saved an object into Core Data without setting `datum`. This would only be possible if you have marked the `datum` attribute as optional in the data model editor.

But accidentally saving unfinished object sometimes happens during development. That's why your code has to match the attribute configuration. An optional attribute that you treat as not-optional in code is a bad idea.

---

You should make the attribute not-optional in the data model editor, so saves will fail if the object is not setup completely. You will find that setting in the attribute sidebar in the model editor.

Or you have to treat the attribute as optional in your code as well.

i.e.:

```
if let dateFromCell = object.valueForKey("datum") as? NSDate {
    var dateString = Date.toString(date: dateFromCell!)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use the force-unwrap operator (the exclamation mark) unless you are absolutely sure it cannot be nil.

Adding a force-unwrap is equivalent to adding a `NSAssert(myVar != nil)`. So whenever you use an exclamation mark somewhere, you might as well write explicitly the assert. At least you'll know exactly why your program crashed.